# How to transfer object through two processes?

Tags: java, process

For example , I develop a connection pool as a server , and on the other application I want to use the connection existing in the pool , How can I get it ? they are in two processes ? and have different life circle ?

Comment: You can't serialize connections of any kind. The concept doesn't begin to make sense. -1

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about socket connections (i.e. your connection pool handles tcp connections), then you can't pass that connection from one process to another. However, you could have a connection from the second process to the server and relay the information to the second process (essentially acting as a proxy).

In general, you will need a way for the two processes to communicate. If they have a different lifecycle (which you hint at) and you need one process to pick up messages from the other process when it comes on line, then you will need a persistence and queuing mechanism as well. Depending on your needs there are many different ways to achieve this. Here are some examples: -

1. On the server, write the information to a socket and read it on the other process. You would use one of the Java messaging classes and might serialiaze the object information. This is non-persistent, but might be the easiest to begin with.
2. On the server, write the information to a file and signal either by a named semaphore, file or other means that there is information to be processed.
3. On the server, write the message to a guaranteed delivery queue (e.g. Amazon or Azure queue) so that it can be picked up by the other process when available.